# Express - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I know that it's a question frequently asked but cannot figure out what's the problem here:

```
 router.post('/garage/cart',
    app.requirePermission([
        ['allow', {
            users: '@'
        }],
        ['deny', {
            users: '*'
        }]
    ]),
    function(req, res){
        var body = req.body;
        if(body.vehicleId 
            && body.garageId 
            && body.prestationId 
            && body.minPrice
            && body.maxPrice)
        {
            app.services.garage.createVirtualCart(body.vehicleId, body.garageId, function(cartId){
                var item = {
                    quote : {
                        quoteType : "ONLINE",
                        carServiceId : body.prestationId,
                        price : {
                            minPriceExclTax : parseFloat(body.minPrice),
                            maxPriceExclTax : parseFloat(body.maxPrice),
                        }
                    },
                    quantity : 1
                };

                app.services.garage.addItemsToCart(cartId, item, function(){
                    var partnerCart = app.models.PartnerCart.build();
                    partnerCart.cart_object = JSON.stringify(item);
                    partnerCart.cart_createdate = new Date();
                    partnerCart.cart_accountid = req.account.act_id;
                    partnerCart.cart_carid = body.vehicleId;
                    partnerCart.save();

                    return res.json({
                        code: 0,
                        cart: cartId
                    });
                }, 
                function(message){
                    sendErrorMessage(res, message);
                });

            }, 
            function(message){
                sendErrorMessage(res, message);
            });               
        }else{
            sendErrorMessage(res, "Params to create a cart and add an item to it is not suffisiant or not well formed.");
        }
    }
);
```

I'm getting the error in the callback of ***addItemsToCart***. It's not even saving the record. But if I remove this part of code:

```
return res.json({
                   code: 0,
                   cart: cartId
                });
```

There is no error and the record is saved properly.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `app.requirePermission()`?  I don't see any obvious place in the code you show that sends a response before your `res.json()` unless one of your `sendErrorMessage()` calls is getting triggered.

Comment: the ***res.json()***  is being here to send the response back but it seems to crash because of it

Comment: That's just a symptom that you're doing something wrong elsewhere in the code (sending a response somewhere else when you don't intend to).  The `res.json()` is not the cause of the problem.  You want that there.  The cause is whatever else is sending a response when it shouldn't be.  As a diagnostic hint, when you remove the `res.json()` what is the actual response that the client sees?  That might be a clue to what other code is sending a response when it shouldn't.

Comment: Is it an async code here `partnerCart.save();`? I assume it takes a callback and you need to `return res.json({ code: 0, cart: cartId });` from that callback once the `save()` is done. `Save()` may return an error however you have already returned `res.json` ...

Comment: This happens when response was delivered to client and again you are trying to give response